# Oracle: comparing the column value with previous records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table which is being loaded by a function - whenever it finds "LOW_MEMORY" in best_status, it will add the systimestamp in low_mem_timestamp column.

```
+----------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| device_id| best_status       | job_id| low_mem_timestamp             |
+----------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| 715016   | OPERATION_FAILURE | 511008|(null)                         |
| 715009   | LOW_MEMORY        | 511008|10-MAY-17 11.13.22.143122000 AM|
| 715014   | DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE | 740004|(null)                         |
| 941015   | LOW_MEMORY        | 740004|10-MAY-17 11.13.22.143122000 AM|
+----------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
```

After this I have another table where i want to record the changes from above table

Whenever low_mem_timestamp changes for any device_id like:

1. if it had timestamp and now it got updated to "null" then it should add "1"
2. if it had null value and got updated to timestamp then "0"

Output table:

Condition:

1. device_id='715009' BEST STATUS moved from "LOW_MEMORY" to "UPDATE_DEFERRED" then low_mem_timstamp got updated to "null" then low_mem_timstamp should be "1"
2. device_id='715014' BEST STATUS moved from " DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" to "LOW_MEMORY" then low_mem_timestamp got updated to some timestamp "any timestamp" then low_mem_timstamp should be "0"
3. device_id='941015' BEST STATUS remains same, it is not updated then low_mem_timstamp should be "NA"

Then in my final table output should be like

```
  +----------+-------------------+-------+---------------+
    | device_id| best_status       | job_id| low_mem_toggle|
    +----------+-------------------+-------+---------------+
    | 715009   | UPDATE_DEFERRED   | 511008|1              |
    | 715014   | LOW_MEMORY        | 740004|0              |
    | 941015   | LOW_MEMORY        | 740004|NA             |
    +----------+-------------------+-------+---------------+
```

Please suggest a sql query to implement this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 'if it had timestamp and now it got updated to "null" then I want "1" ' - In what field do you want the 1?

Comment: probably you wanted to have trigger

Comment: Please see updated details